# Вычислить результат, объединив таблицу в горизонтальную и вертикальную в yiii2

Tags: yii2, gridview

У меня есть 2 модели в Yiii2. В одной - названия государств, а во второй - данные, относящиеся к этому государству. Мне нужно объединить все это в горизонтальном и вертикальном положении, и вывести все это в одно окно. Например, название государства и его жителей. Страна и Датас. Таблица данных содержит country_id. На основании этого я должен назвать данные. Сделать это с помощью сетки или простой тег таблицы. Подскажите возможные варианты, пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, более читабельнее будет, если в первой колонке расположить названия стран, а в других колонках отобразить данные городов. Отображение таблицы может выглядеть следующим образом:
Без виджета

```
<?php
/** @var array $countries */
?>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Peoples</th>
        <th>Rivers</th>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($countries as $country):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $country->name ?></td>
        <td><?= $country->datas->peoples ?></td>
        <td><?= $country->datas->rivers ?></td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

С виджетом (не помню, как вывести названия колонок)

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'name',
        [
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->datas->peoples;
            }
        ],
        [
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->datas->rivers;
            }
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: спасибо попробую и ответ напишу